# iOS + Facebook: Search for specific user's status

Tags: ios, facebook, search, graph

There's probably a simple answer to this question, although despite hours of searching I can't find it. I am comfortable with the basics of Facebook search but what I need to do is to specify a specific user (not the user of the app) and pull that user's statuses. For whatever reason I can't figure out how to do this, nor can I figure out the correct permissions to pass with the Facebook request.

Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You can't "search" for a specific user via the Search API. In v1.0 of the Graph API, it is/was possible the request the public posts like this:

```
GET /4/posts
```

Try it here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=4%2Fposts&version=v1.0 This returns the public posts of Mark Zuckerberg. In Graph API v2.0, this is no longer possible:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=4%2Fposts&version=v2.0

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

Comment: Hi Tobi, Thanks! So is it possible to do this with any functionality within Facebook's API, or is it impossible to search for the statuses of a specific user?